# Android - getting dimensions of stretchable area in NinePatchDrawable

Tags: android, resources, nine-patch

How can I get the dimensions of a 9patch image stretchable / content area?
I couldn't find an appropriate method. The closest value I got was the result of getPadding(). The top/left coordinates corresponded to the content area but bottom/right had the identical values.

```
NinePatchDrawable image = NinePatchDrawable.class.cast(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_frame));
Rect p = new Rect();
image.getPadding(p);
Log.d("9PATCH", p.toString();
```

And I got: "Rect(9, 9 - 9, 9)"

Comment: Why do you want those dimensions?

Comment: I meanwhile solved my original problem with a different approach but I'm still curious how to do it.